# Placeholder in Textarea is not showing up

Tags: html, placeholder

I have no clue why the placeholder is not showing up in the textarea:

```
<textarea id="message" tabindex="4" cols="39" name="message" rows="7" 
    placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
<input id="sendto" name="sendto" type="hidden" 
    value="benjamin@example.com" />
```

Comment: This works for me in Firefox. What browser are you looking at it in?

Comment: Chrome Version 42.0.2311.135
...just tested with Firefox 29.0.1 - still not working

Comment: Can you see it in this http://jsfiddle.net/tLdp29k2/ ?

Comment: Yes. In both browsers...

Comment: Are you using html5, did you add  <!DOCTYPE html> ?

Comment: Of course I have the doctype attribute in my header section...
But easy... it'll work without placeholder too. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will be helpful, but:

- http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#attr-textarea-placeholder
- http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#attr-input-placeholder

Here is the **documentatcion from W3C** and information that **placeholder is valid for both: textarea, and input**.

In that case if Your browser does not show it and everything is done as it should (html5 doctype, and good html structure of whole file), then it is nothing to worry about. Maybe this is some kind of bug, or temporary problem, or something else.

**IMPORTANT!** Remember to **add label to each input or textarea** (as stated in documentary file), and then placeholder is kind of *additional convenience*.

Comment: That's the point :). But if You are one hundred percent sure that your document is valid, you can send some code to chrome developers, and maybe you just found a new bug. Nevertheless this is additional functionality, and if it doesn't work in one specific browser, there is no need to worry. Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

try this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder
and
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

cool tutorials for anyone facing placeholder issues, but if your input is created from codes and not HTML use aria placeholder

link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-placeholder